# Resultant Array is not According to Code

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays as follows:

```
$my = Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 8 )

$all = Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => Lahore ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [name] => Gujrat ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 3 [name] => Rawalpindi ) [3] => Array ( [id] => 4 [name] => Karachi  ) [4] => Array ( [id] => 5 [name] => Islamabad ) [5] => Array ( [id] => 6 [name] => Manga  ) [6] => Array ( [id] => 7 [name] => Gulberg ) [7] => Array ( [id] => 8 [name] => Muridkey  ) [8] => Array ( [id] => 9 [name] => Queta ) )
```

I want a resultant array like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => Lahore )  [8] => Array ( [id] => 9 [name] => Queta ) )
```

My Code is as follows:

```
for($m=0; $m< sizeof($all); $m++){
            foreach($my as $key => $value){
                if($all[$m]['id'] !== $value){
                    unset($all[$m]);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Its an array of associative arrays.

Comment: I have a large array and a small array. I want to keep only those elements in large array which are present in the small array.

Comment: in small array do you have required keys or ids ?

Comment: For the future please include the result of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) function to save only items with ids from $my array

```
$res = array_filter($all, 
    function ($x) use($my) {
       return in_array($x['id'], $my); });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the arrays from `$all` indexed by the `id`s and then check for common keys by flipping `$my`:

```
$result = array_intersect_key(array_column($all, null, 'id'), array_flip($my));
```

Your result shows  that you don't use `id` but the current index, but your code shows using `id`.  So if you don't use the `id`, then forget the re-indexing and just flip `$my` and check for common keys:

```
$result = array_intersect_key($all, array_flip($my));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code unsets all keys that are not equal to 1 and 8. This is impossible and you get an empty array. If you want to keep both loops you could use:

```
$output = array();
for($m=0; $m< sizeof($all); $m++){
        foreach($my as $key => $value){
            if($all[$m]['id'] !== $value){
                $output[$m] = $all[$m]);
                break;
            }
        }
}
$all = $output;
```

Or you can use unset and [in_array](http://php.net/manual/de/function.in-array.php):

```
for($m=0; $m< sizeof($all); $m++){
        if(!in_array($all[$m]['id'], $my, true)) { 
            unset($all[$m]);
            break;
        }
}
```